# Super Computer made out of XBox 360

Tags: computer-building

What is the super-computer that was all over the news, that was made from an Xbox 360?

What changes would you have to make to a normal desktop to turn it into a supercomputer?

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean the [PS3 one](http://blogs.zdnet.com/storage/?p=220)

Answer (score 2):

The Xbox 360 is by no means a super-computer. It's parts are somewhat outdated, you could build a machine to outthink it with a couple of hundred pounds.

To turn a regular desktop into a supercomputer? I believe that's the purpose of the nVidia Tesla card :) (they start at about $1000, still much cheaper than your average supercomputer)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this one?  http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/technology/8254159.stm

Typical slow news day puff piece, the XBox GPU isn't even as good as the PS3 cell for this sort of stuff.

ps. Interesting coincidence between the notoriously publicity hungry CS dept in question and you userid.